# Converting varchar to float or the way around

Tags: sql, excel, casting

I have imported an excel document I have received into my mssql database..
Everything went through fine and I have a table with 7000 records consisting of 2 columns.
Now I want to join this excel table with an already existing table in my database to compare some data I have stored there:

```
SELECT  b.ID, a.ID , b.NAME   
FROM ExcelTable b
inner join DB_Table a
on a.ID = cast(b.ID as varchar)
```

The ID's in my database are stored as VARCHAR(20) and the ExcelTable ID getting imported as floats without a possible way to change the type. The Above sql is not getting me any results at all, even though I know the records do exist. 
I believe that my float ID's are stored with the ".00000" after the original ID which is why it's not working.

Can anyone help me to fix this issue please

Comment: Cast the varchar as float instead of casting the float as varchar in your comparison?  In other words change your "on" clause to "on cast(a.Id AS float) = b.ID".

Comment: Hi, I have tried and i get this error Error converting data type varchar to float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I assume that the IDs in your tables are integers?  In which case this should work:

```
SELECT  
    b.ID, 
    a.ID, 
    b.NAME   
FROM 
    ExcelTable b
    INNER JOIN DB_Table a ON CONVERT(INT, a.ID) = CONVERT(INT, b.ID);
```

If you have anything non-numeric in your DB Table then this will fail, as you will get an error about converting VARCHAR to INT.  If this is the case then you might get away with this:

```
SELECT  
    b.ID, 
    a.ID, 
    b.NAME   
FROM 
    ExcelTable b
    INNER JOIN DB_Table a ON a.ID = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), CONVERT(INT, b.ID));
```

Now we are converting the floating point number to an integer, which will drop off the ".0000" part, then converting this to VARCHAR to allow comparison to your database table.

EDIT: So it turns out that your numbers are too big to be converted to INTs, so try BIGINTs instead:

```
SELECT  
    b.ID, 
    a.ID, 
    b.NAME   
FROM 
    ExcelTable b
    INNER JOIN DB_Table a ON a.ID = CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), CONVERT(BIGINT, b.ID));
```

Comment: Hi Richard thanks for your answer.
The id is not the real id of the table and on DB_Table it's a varchar(25) and on the excel table it's a float type. When I try your methode i get the following error: Arithmetic overflow error for type int, value = 3490001445329.000000.
I believe the issue is the ".000000." the comma and zeros should not be there. I tried (REPLACE) still not working..

Comment: Okay, your numbers are too big to convert to INTs, so try BIGINT instead?  In other words change the last CONVERT to CONVERT(BIGINT, b.ID).